# typescript: как изменить значение переменной в основном модуле

Tags: typescript, ссылки

комрады.
есть кусок кода Unit1, в котором:

```
let x1
Case1:{
    return this.remote
    //кусок кода
    .then(()=>Unit2.getText(x1))
    .then(()=>Method1(x1))
    //неинтересный кусок кода
}`
```

и Unit2, в котором:

```
getText(text): Command<void>{
        return Unit2.getText(this.parent, text)
}
static  getText(command:Command<any>, text): Command <void>{
    return command
    //кусок кода для забирания текста со страницы
    .getVisibleText()
    .then(function (visibletext) {text = visibletext;})
}`
```

вопрос: есть ли возможность из Unit2 изменить значение переменной x1 из Unit1
например, x1 заменить значение на text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решено заменой переменной на объект с свойствами

```
export class X1 {
    first_property:string;  
}

let x1 = new X1();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .then(()=>Unit2.getText(x1))
> ```

```
.then(() => x1 = Unit2.getText(x1))
```

Comment: после выполнения х1 = [object Object], значение не передалось

Comment: `.then(() => Unit2.getText(x1)).then(t => x1 = t)` - а так? Хотя, на самом деле тебя надо `.then(() => Unit2.getText(x1)).then(x => Method1(x))`

Comment: теперь в каждом из вариантов x1 = undefined, может как то через глобальную буферную переменную это организовать ? но я не очень представляю как, и второй вариант не очень подойдет т.к. в дальнейшей x1 может трансформироваться или иначе применяться